# Delete information from transaction logs at SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Console application uses sql request BACKUP DATABASE to create .bak file
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304(v=sql.105).aspx

It works good, but transaction logs contain information about this backup (and restore). How can I delete this information from transaction logs programmatically? Or can I backup/restore sql database without adding this information to transaction logs?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Huh??? Of course the transaction logs contain these details. If you are trying to make that not be in the transaction it sounds like something fishy is going on here. Why do you need to cover your tracks?

Comment: My application can overflow transaction logs and I want to delete all information associated with my application

Comment: >>>My application can overflow transaction logs and I want to delete all information associated with my application<<< 1.To delete smth you shuold first write smth, so if you overflow, you cannot delete 2. You cannot overflow log file writing info about backup/restore, it's pretty small 3. Backup/restore info has nothing to do with your application

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do any modification insiTransaction log

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SIMPLE` recovery model, use `CHECKPOINT` to truncate the log.

If you are in `FULL` or `BULK LOGGED`, backup your log (you may need to repeat this operation if log is not truncated for some reason)

But what do you think it contains? There is no real data (reguarding backup) in there, only information about differential bitmap changes